# NIFI PutHDFS fails to write the contents

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm newbie of Nifi

I'm trying to get data from database and put it to hadoop.

It seems i succeed to connect hadoop from nifi using PutHDFS processor.

After running PutHDFS, a file is created successfully.

But the problem is.. the file is empty. no contents.

I tried to get a file from local nifi server using GetFile, but the result is same. so there is no problem from source.

I have no idea why NIFI fails to write the contents into hadoop file. There is even no error occured.

please help me.

Comment: Please share your flow (or export it as a template) and the configuration of the processors you're using. The likely reason is that the flowfile being sent to the `PutHDFS` processor has no content, and you can examine that by stopping the `PutHDFS` processor and listing the contents of the queue leading to it to examine those flowfiles.

Comment: Please first check if the FlowFile has content in it by stopping `PutHDFS` and let the FlowFiles queue up. The FlowFile size is displayed on the queued up relationship. If it is `0 KB`, it is safe to say that the FlowFile has no content in it/

Comment: I checked the flowfile and it had contents as AVRO format. I think it's not a problem of configuration from source but destination(putHDFS).